# Reading and writing Serializable objects using NIO

Tags: java, file, serialization

I have created the following class to read Serializable object from file and write to a file.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;

/**
 * Class FileSerializeStreamer is used to read and write Serialise object to
 * file.
 * 
 * @author TapasB
 */
public class FileSerializeStreamer {

    /**
     * Constructor FileSerializeStreamer
     * 
     * @author TapasB
     */
    public FileSerializeStreamer() {

    }

    /**
     * Method readSerializable reads the Serialised object from file and
     * returns. If the file is null or doesn't exist then it returns null
     * without throwing any error.
     * 
     * @author TapasB
     * @param file
     *            - the instance of the file to read from.
     * @param clazz
     *            - the class type of the object.
     * @return the instance of the object.
     */
    public <T extends Serializable> T readSerializable(File file, Class<T> clazz) {
        if (file == null || !file.exists()) {
            return null;
        }

        RandomAccessFile serFile = null;
        FileChannel fileChannel = null;
        byte[] bytes = null;

        try {
            serFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
            fileChannel = serFile.getChannel();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) serFile.length());
            FileLock fileLock = fileChannel.lock();
            fileChannel.read(buffer);
            fileLock.release();
            bytes = buffer.array();
            buffer.clear();
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            cause.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeStream(fileChannel);
            closeStream(serFile);
        }

        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = null;
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;

        try {
            byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
            return clazz.cast(objectInputStream.readObject());
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            cause.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeStream(objectInputStream);
            closeStream(byteArrayInputStream);
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Method writeSerializable writes the Serialised object to the given file.
     * If the file is null or doesn't exist then it returns without throwing any
     * error.
     * 
     * @author TapasB
     * @param file
     *            - the instance of the file to write to.
     * @param serialized
     *            - the instance to be written.
     */
    public <T extends Serializable> void writeSerializable(File file, T serialized) {
        if (file == null || !file.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;

        try {
            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(serialized);
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            cause.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeStream(objectOutputStream);
        }

        RandomAccessFile serFile = null;
        FileChannel fileChannel = null;

        try {
            byte[] source = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            serFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
            fileChannel = serFile.getChannel();
            ByteBuffer buffer = fileChannel.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, source.length);
            FileLock fileLock = fileChannel.lock();
            buffer.put(source);
            fileLock.release();
            buffer.clear();
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            cause.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
            closeStream(fileChannel);
            closeStream(serFile);
        }
    }

    // Method closeStream
    private void closeStream(Closeable closeable) {
        try {
            if (closeable != null) {
                closeable.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            cause.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know

- If there is any drawback present in the code?
- Is the right way to do it?
- What happens if the size of the data that I want to read or write exceeds the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`? How to handle that scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why? Why use NIO? You are reading the data in to a buffer, completely, then you are performing the deserialization from that. What advantages of NIO are you using?

Even using your system, though, you should be using try-with-resources, and you should use the [`FileChannel.open(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) mechanism for it...

```
try (FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(file.getPath())) {
    ... do something with the channel
} catch (IOException ...) {
    ....
    return null;
}
```

But, given your use case, I would simply do:

```
try {
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(file.getPath());
    try (ObjectINputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))) {
        return clazz.cast(ois.readObject());
    } catch (....) {
        ... deserialization problem
    }
} catch (....) {
    ... IO Problem
}
```

If you really require the file locking, then do it all in one process anyway, and don't use the intermediate byte[] array:

```
try (FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(file.getPath())) {
    FileLock lock = channel.lock();
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(channel))) {
         return clazz.cast(ois.readObject());
    } finally {
        lock.release();
    }
    try (ObjectINputStream
}
```

Note, all the comments on the reading side, also apply to the writing side too. You can convert your serialization to match the same concepts as well.

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my code. Since I am using JDK6 I don't have many of the methods that you have mentioned. But I understand the parts that you have mentioned. But still I am thinking if the file is a large one and cannot be converted to a byte array

Comment: Using the `Channels.newInputStream` will remove the need for the byte[] array entirely. That will remove the issue with large files entirely too (if the data was OK to serialize, then it will be OK to read too).